# Perl script to execute commands in cisco router

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm new to perl.I was trying to login to a cisco router to execute few commands.
I was able to login using [`Net::SSH::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl) and execute a couple of commands. 
But when i tried to switch to the configure mode the script fails.

```
br-waas#

br-waas#configure

br-waas(config)#
```

Is there a perl cpan module to do this?

```
use  Net::SSH::Perl;

my $host = "XX.XX.XX.XX";
my $user = "XXXX";
my $password = "XXXX";

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
$ssh->login($user, $password);

print "check the version of the build \n";
my ($stdout) = $ssh->cmd("show statistics accelerator http object-cache");
print $stdout;

sleep(3);

print "enter the config mode \n";
my($stdout1) = $ssh->cmd("config");
print "$stdout1 \n";
```

When the configure command executes the script fails with the following error. `% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.`

Comment: How does the script fail?  What exactly do you observe?  Where is the code that you've used thus far?

Comment: @Miller I have added the code above.When the configure command executes the script fails with the following error. % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble with Net:SSH, [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.60/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm) has always done the job well for me.

If you have an enable password, at the end of the day, you're going to need something implementing Expect, which is always a hassle.

Comment: I don't have an enable password.

Comment: Net::SSH::Expect helps. Thanks

Comment: Net::SSH::Expect is quite unreliable due to the way it works internally.

Answer (score 1):

The one library that worked for me is NET::Appliance::Session.
It is reliable, solves the "channel locking" issue en cisco routers/switches and can send commands without the use of expect (or at least does it internally can't remember well)

Answer (score 0):

Does the command "config" work when doing this by hand? I assume you will get a question echoed back on the terminal.

If this is a plain Cisco router running IOS, the command to enter config mode is "configure terminal".